# OWL Properties domain and range inheritance semantics

Tags: jena, owl, protege, reasoning, pellet

Actually, I'm getting lost with domain and range semantics when a subsummption exists, in addition to restriction inheritance between class taxonomy members. Please see the following cases.

Let's consider

```
(1) hasCar Domain driver
(2) driver subClassOf human
```

Then, can we infer that

```
hasCar Domain human
```

Let's have `hasCar (x, y)` whatever x is

from (1): `driver(x)`
from (2): `human(x)`

then: whatever `x` is, if `hasCar(x, y)` => `driver (x)` =>

```
(3) hasCar Domain human
```

**First Question:** Is this conclusion correct? Why isn't Protege 5 with Hermit (neither Pellet, not even Jena with some reasoner) inferring that?

---

Let's consider

```
(1) hasAudiCar Range AudiCar 
(2) AudiCar subClassOf Car
```

In a similar fashion, we can infer that

```
(3) hasAudiCar Range Car
```

**Second Question:** Is this conclusion correct? Why isn't Protege 5 with Hermit (neither Pellet, not even Jena with some reasoner) inferring that?

---

Let's consider

```
(1) hasAudiCar Domain driver 
(2) hasAudiCar Range audiCar
(3) driver hasAudiCar min 1 audiCar
(4) audiCar subClassOf car
```

Then, we can infer that

```
driver hasAudiCar min 1 car
```

**Third Question:** Is this conclusion correct? Why isn't Protege 5 with Hermit (neither Pellet, not even Jena with some reasoner) inferring that?

**UPDATE**

Using Jena with the specification `OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF` gives my expected results! However, using Jena with Pellet doesn't, neither using Protege with Hermit or Pellet!

Answer (score 1):

First Answer: It is, it is not explicitly showing it in Protege. (Source: running this example in protege, running similar experiments with pellet in Apache Jena)

Second Answer: No, we cannot infer this. You can consider sub-classes to be akin to a sub-set. Therefore properties of the superclass are applicable to the subclass, not the other way around. You have very specifically defined

```
(1) hasAudiCar Range AudiCar 
(2) AudiCar subClassOf Car
```

Therefore we know that `AudiCar` is a subset of Car and that the property `hasAudiCar` is only applicable to this subset. Thus we cannot say `hasAudiCar Range Car`.

Third Answer: No, again this is the same logical fallacy as before. If you want to *specify* that `driver hasAudiCar min 1 car` then the property must be defined on the respective superclasses, i.e, `human` and `car` as 
`hasAudiCar Domain Human` 
`hasAudiCar Range Car`

Additional Info: It is rare to want to infer class restrictions and actually more advantageous to specify them outright so that they can drive inference. For example you can define a class `AudiCarDriver` as equivalent to `Driver and hasAudiCar min 1 AudiCar` thus classifying all drivers with at least 1 audi as `AudiCarDrivers`

Do also refer to the owl language reference here http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/ 
 if this is still confusing you. Hope I helped :)